# Webalizer: website/stats doesn't show index.html but directory listing

Tags: configuration, webserver, apache-httpd

I'm working with Linux and want to provide my users with up-to-date statistics of their website. ex: user1 has a website on my Linux DNS server: `user1.be` but when he surfs to `user1.be/stats` he has to see the stats of his website.

Now I installed `webalizer` and did:

```
webalizer -n hostname -o /path/to/webalizer/output /path/to/logfile.log
```

which works great but when the user surfs to user1.be/stats he sees the directory listing (`index.html`, `usage.png`, `daily_usage.png`, ...) *But* I want him to directly see `index.html` when surfing to `user1.be/stats`.

Also in my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` I got the following listed:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var homepage.html index.php
```

How can this be accomplished, cause I can't figure it out...

Comment: @countermode - make sure when you're editing that you see if someone else has edited it before you. I just added those tags that you overrode 8-).

Answer (score 0):

#### Idea #1 - Is it running?

After making those changes to your Apache `httpd.conf` file, did you restart it?

```
$ sudo service httpd restart
```

#### Idea #2 - right httpd.conf?

Are you sure that this `httpd.conf` file is the appropriate one for your Apache you're connecting to? There are many ways to diagnose this, I generally like to check the `httpd` executable to see where it's looking for things, first.

```
$ httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Fedora)
Server built:   Jul 23 2014 10:29:44
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:36
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Compiled using: APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Here you can see that it's looking in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` for this file.

#### Idea #3 - logs

Take a look at the logs. These are visible here (again you can find this info out from the output above).

```
$ tail -f /etc/httpd/logs/error_logs
```

There's typically other log files, such as `access_log` in that same directory too.

#### Idea #4 - where's httpd?

You can use `lsof` to determine which `httpd` you're actually using like so:

```
$ sudo lsof -p $(pgrep -u root httpd) | grep /httpd$
httpd   22695 root  txt    REG            253,0   511936  1317241 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

So from the above we can see we're using `/usr/sbin/httpd`.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer but yet no results

Comment: @user3629755 - what are the permissions on the `index.html` & other files? Are they such that the user httpd is running as can access them?